# Azure IoT Upload File to Blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Does the upload file to blob feature of the azure-iot-sdk-c currently implement any integrity  checks such as an md5 hash of the blob contents? I am aware of the c-sharp sdk doing this, but I  need confirmation on the c sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only mentioning of hashing for azure-iot-sdk-c, is through the use of **hsm_client_sign_with_identity**, for custom **HSM**, the documentation can be found [**here**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/provisioning_client/devdoc/using_custom_hsm.md). C# and Python do have the abilities stated in this **[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security)**

Comment: Using the Azure Storage SDK I can achieve this correct?

Comment: yes it is supported in the Storage SDK, this is an old but still valid blog post about it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2011/02/17/windows-azure-blob-md5-overview/ 
I hope this helps.

Comment: @radish25 I'd appreciate if you could either upvote or mark as an answer the proposed answer if it helped resolve your question. This would help future community members find the question and response in the future, and it would keep our Azure Community close to quick answers :) 
Thanks !

Comment: Hey Adam, one more quick question. The communication between the iot device and hub for the purposes of storage occurs over https. Does this allow me to rest assured that the content of my upload is unchanged. I found that with the storage API you can set an MD5 hash but one of the MSFT developers mentioned that https by default will also prevent against bitflips. Is this the case?

Comment: @radish25 Correct https protects you from bitflips on the storage service, this pertains to python blockblobservice but same is valid for others: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob/blockblobservice.py#L152 
Line 152 through 171 discusses this case.